# Apache Beam on Spark runner: Why scheduling Delay is increasing in Streaming jobs?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, streaming, delay, apache-beam

I defined a pipeline that reads from a Kafka topic, performs some steps and pubmished the results to an output Kafka topic.

All was fine when I tested it in direct runner mode.

But, when I submit the beam application to spark I got a strenge behavious :
- Scheduling delay increases.

[image]

After long time of investigation I figured it out that the duration of the batch is too small (500 millisecinds).

Following this link

[Pipeline options for the Spark Runner](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/runners/spark/#pipeline-options-for-the-spark-runner)

I added this option to the spark-submit:

--batchIntervalMillis=2000

Now all is back to normal:

[image]

Don't hesitate to share you opinion.
Regards,
Ali

Comment: Hi, did you figure this out? I am having the same issue.